# How can I rip off the refresh/stop button from the navigation bar in Firefox 29?

Tags: firefox

How can I rip off the refresh/stop button from the navigation bar in Firefox 29 so that I can customize its location like any other button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Classic Theme Restorer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) and Mozilla's [guide to making FF 29 look like the old FF](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-make-new-firefox-look-like-old-firefox).

Editing The Classic Theme Restorer's options for `Movable back-forward button` and `Combine stop & reload buttons` then customizing the layout did the trick for my FF 29 install.

Hope that can help.